# Upper limits inequality

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show that for two sequences $f_n,g_n$ that are non-negative and bounded that $ \limsup(f_ng_n) \le (\limsup (f_n))(\limsup (g_n)) $. I have come up with the example where $f_n$ is a repeating sequence $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $g_n$ is a repeating sequence $\{(1/2),(1/3),(1/4),(1/5)\}$ then  $ \limsup(f_ng_n)= 4/5 $ but $(\limsup (f_n))(\limsup (g_n)) = 2 $. Now to put this in words it seems like the product of largest sub-sequential limit of each sequence is larger or equal to the largest sub-sequential limit of the multiples of the $n$'th entries for  $ \limsup(f_ng_n)$ but I am unsure how to express this algebraically.

Essentially that the largest sub-sequential limits of each sequence may be larger than the largest sub-sequential of the product $f_ng_n$.

Comment: Use the definition of $\limsup$, and that $\sup\limits_{k\ge n}{f_kg_k}\leq\sup\limits_{k\ge n}{f_k}\sup\limits_{k\ge n}{g_k}$. So you only have to prove the last inequality.

Comment: @Svetoslav, can you elaborate please.

Comment: James, I see that you haven't voted yet for any answer or question. Voting helps the proper functioning of the MSE site. If you think an answer is helpful than you may upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $k\ge n\in\mathbb N$ 
$$f_kg_k\leq \sup\limits_{k\ge n}{f_k}\sup\limits_{k\ge n}{g_k}$$
Now the right hand side is a fixed number and you can take supremum on both sides over $k\ge n$ and so you get
$$\sup\limits_{k\ge n}{f_kg_k}\leq \sup\limits_{k\ge n}{f_k}\sup\limits_{k\ge n}{g_k}$$
Finally you let $n\to\infty$ and the result follows by the definition of $\limsup$.

**Note** that as both sequences are bounded from above and below by $0$ so is the sequence of the products $f_kg_k$ and therefore $\sup\limits_{k\ge n}{f_kg_k}$ exists for each $n$ and the sequence $\sup\limits_{k\ge n}{f_kg_k}$ is decreasing $\Rightarrow$ the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\sup\limits_{k\ge n}{f_kg_k}}$ exists. The same goes for the limit on the right: the sequence $\sup\limits_{k\ge n}{f_k}\sup\limits_{k\ge n}{g_k}$ is bounded from above, and from below by $0$, and decreasing $\Rightarrow$ has a limit. Also, because each of the sequences $\sup\limits_{k\ge n}{f_k}$ and $\sup\limits_{k\ge n}{g_k}$ possesses a limit, the limit of the product is equal to the product of the limits.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_n=\sup \{ f_n,f_{n+1},\dots \}$, $B_n=\sup \{ g_n,g_{n+1},\dots \}$ and $C_n=\sup\{ f_n g_n,\dots\}$

Since $f_k g_k\leq A_n B_n$ for any $k\geq n$ we have

$$
\lim\sup (f_n g_n)=\lim C_n\leq \lim(A_nB_n)=\lim A_n\lim B_n=\lim\sup f_n\lim\sup g_n
$$

Comment: What does it mean to multiply $A_n$ and $B_n$ ? They are sets !

Comment: I forgot to put $\sup$